# Asterisk AGI with C problems

Tags: c, asterisk, agi

EHLO everybody

I am into AGI with C language, and after a while I got a issue. When I playback a file to the channel with `GET DATA` (and other AGI commands), I need to apply a sleep function so this can be played and the user has time to hear it.

My partial code is like this:

```
 char line[80];
 int digit;
 setlinebuf(stdout);
 setlinebuf(stderr);
 printf("ANSWER\n");  
 printf("GET DATA en/pbx-transfer 5000 4 \n"); 
 sleep(3);
 printf("CHANNEL STATUS\n");
 printf("HANGUP");
```

Asterisk shows me a warning about my use of `sleep()` like this:

```
The FD we were waiting for has something waiting. Waitfordigit returning numeric 1
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - no need reinvent the Wheel. There are more then one AGI interface implemntation for c/c++

You have no use sleep,threads,waits etc inside agi script.

AGI architecture is example of blocking by STD input. Just wait for input(READ from STD) and it will return you info when it ready.

If you use it, such message is normal and expected. You can use non-blocking versions of sleep.

ALSO  you have not use GET DATA if you not need DATA. You can use STREAM

Comment: 1) This is a learning process, so that is why I'm into this, actually I use for productions environments asterisk-perl.
2) I did used fgets but instead I recieve a "200" answer from Asterisk. I remember asterisk-perl have the same problem, I had to add 3 seconds silence before a get data.

Comment: You get 200 on login. You have read all response. Asterisk agi working ok.

Comment: yeah 200 is an OK, but if I ask asterisk to play a file, at least should play it without I put a sleep?.

Comment: Please use already developed AGI package or do your logic STRICTLY as described in AGI spec. If you read all responses, you just need wait for new response while it playing file. There are no other answer posible here.AGI work ok,yes, it work ok in C/C++ too.